# Got the wrong query in mongo query with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am using the nodeJS and MongoDB. I have lots of search options. I have run the below search:

```
const {keyword, postedfromDate, postedtoDate} = req.body;
    let searchp = {}
    let keywordquery = "";
    let postedfromdatequery = "";
    let postedtodatequery = "";
    if (keyword && keyword !== '') {
        keywordquery = {$or: [{ subject: new RegExp(keyword) }, { desc: new RegExp(keyword) }, { solnbr: new RegExp(keyword) }]}
    }
    if((postedfromDate && postedfromDate!=='') || (postedtoDate && postedtoDate!=='')){
        if(postedfromDate && postedfromDate!==''){
            //console.log("Posted From Date: ", postedfromDate)
            let today = new Date(postedfromDate);
            let newdat = today.toISOString().split('T')[0];
            postedfromdatequery = {date: {"$gte": newdat }}
        }
        if(postedtoDate && postedtoDate!==''){
            //console.log("Posted To Date: ", postedtoDate)
            let todate = new Date(postedtoDate);
            let newdate = todate.toISOString().split('T')[0];
            postedtodatequery = {date: {"$lte": newdate }}
        }
    }
    
    console.log("keywordquery", keywordquery)
    console.log("postedfromdatequery", postedfromdatequery)
    console.log("postedtodatequery", postedtodatequery)
        
        searchp = {$and: [
            keywordquery,
            postedfromdatequery,
            postedtodatequery
        ]}
```

In 3 above console, I got the below:

```
keywordquery {
  '$or': [
    { subject: /technical/ },
    { desc: /technical/ },   
    { solnbr: /technical/ }  
  ]
}
postedfromdatequery { date: { '$gte': '2021-09-10' } }
postedtodatequery { date: { '$lte': '2021-09-17' } }
```

In 3 above console everything is OK but when I console the searchp than did not get the expected result. When I console the searchp than get the below:

```
{
  '$and': [ { '$or': [Array] }, { date: [Object] }, { date: [Object] } ]
}
```

Why I get the Array and Object in main query as I am using the correct variables??
Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem here :

when printing complex objects with `console.log` he will abbreviate what he can ( if i am not mistaken , 3 levels down in objects/arrays ) so you are getting this "weird" print but actually everything looks good.

if you want to print the whole object down to the lowest level/depth

use : `console.log(JSON.stringify(searchp))`

Comment: After JSON.stringify, I got the below:

```
{"$and":[{"$or":[{"subject":{}},{"desc":{}},{"solnbr":{}}]},{"date":{"$gte":"2021-09-10"}},{"date":{"$lte":"2021-09-17"}}]}
```
object part is OK but the array part showing blank however I have posted the value in subject, desc, solnbr search fields.

Can you please check

Comment: please provide your full code snippet in order to check what happen there, from what it seems your array of `keywordquery` is filled with empty object